# Isolate Open VPN Connection to User in Windows 11

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn, nas, network-adapter

I am connecting to an Open VPN server and want that connection to only apply to the user who has initiated it, no one else who may be concurrently logged in. I am happy to use OpenVPN GUI, or SoftEther or any Open VPN compatible software.

I have not tried much because I do not know where to start. I do not want to create a whole VM and hope to be able to only isolate the VPN adapter. Ideally, I would do this in the VPN client itself but I have found no such references in either of the two clients I listed above. If it can be done with Windows that would be fine too.

For the server I am connecting to I am only forwarding LAN traffic and not internet wide. It is a Synology NAS that is implementing Open VPN, and must use Open VPN.

Comment: What do you mean by the current user and how are you going to switch users?

Comment: Current Windows user. You can switch between users without logging out, just part of how Windows operates.

Answer (score 1):

For switching users the answer is negative : The VPN creates a virtual
network adapter for the entire computer, and also modifies the routing
table which also serves the entire computer.

As you said, isolating the VPN inside a virtual machine is a solution,
although complicated.
Apart from this, the only answer I can see is to turn off and on the VPN.